# Duplicate values when uploading images using afnetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I want to add multiple images to server, I got code from net and when I'm using it... I'm getting duplicate values as well. I don't have any idea why I'm getting it, example: if I add 2 images, result count is 4, if I add 3 then the result count is 9.In the count for arrayPhotosData.count is 2. for json i have got same (i.e 2 values)

```
for (int i = 0; i<arrayPhotosData.count; i++) {


        CFStringRef fileExtension = (__bridge CFStringRef) [stringFileName pathExtension];
        CFStringRef fileUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, NULL);



        if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeImage))
        {
            NSDictionary *dictionaryFinal =@{@"usrContentFolderId"  : @(0),
                                             @"mediaTypeId"         : @(2),
                                             @"contentTypeId"       : @(intProfileType),
                                             @"userContentFileName" : stringFileName,
                                             @"userContentFileSize" : @(0),
                                             @"makePublic"          : [NSNumber numberWithBool:true]
                                             };
            [arrayPOSTFinalImage addObject:dictionaryFinal];
        }

        else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeMovie))
        {
            NSDictionary *dictionaryFinal =@{@"usrContentFolderId"  : @(0),
                                             @"mediaTypeId"         : @(4),
                                             @"contentTypeId"       : @(intProfileType),
                                             @"userContentFileName" : stringFileName,
                                             @"userContentFileSize" : @(0),
                                             @"makePublic"          : [NSNumber numberWithBool:true]
                                             };
            [arrayPOSTFinalImage addObject:dictionaryFinal];
        }
        else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeText))
        {
            NSDictionary *dictionaryFinal =@{@"usrContentFolderId"  : @(0),
                                             @"mediaTypeId"         : @(1),
                                             @"contentTypeId"       : @(intProfileType),
                                             @"userContentFileName" : stringFileName,
                                             @"userContentFileSize" : @(0),
                                             @"makePublic"          : [NSNumber numberWithBool:true]
                                             };
            [arrayPOSTFinalImage addObject:dictionaryFinal];
        }
    }
    dictionaryUserContentRequest =@{ @"userContentsRequest":arrayPOSTFinalImage};

            NSError *error;


        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionaryUserContentRequest
                                                           options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted             // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                             error:&error];
        if (! jsonData) {
            NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
        } else {
            jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"JSONSTRINGPOSTIMAGE===%@",jsonString);

        }

    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:urlFileUpload parameters:@{@"requestParam":jsonString} constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData)
               {
                   for (int i=0; i<[arrayPhotosData count]; i++)
                   {
                       NSString *stringFileName=arrayFileName[i];
                       CFStringRef fileExtension = (__bridge CFStringRef) [stringFileName pathExtension];
                       CFStringRef fileUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, NULL);

                       if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeImage))
                       {
                           [formData appendPartWithFileData:arrayPhotosData[i] name:@"file" fileName:stringFileName mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
                       }
                       else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeMovie))
                       {
                           [formData appendPartWithFileData:arrayPhotosData[i] name:@"file" fileName:stringFileName mimeType:@"video/quicktime"];
                       }
                       else if ([arrayExtension[i] isEqualToString:@"pdf"])
                       {
                           [formData appendPartWithFileData:arrayPhotosData[i] name:@"file" fileName:stringFileName mimeType:@"application/pdf"];
                       }
                       if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeText))

                       {
                           [formData appendPartWithFileData:arrayPhotosData[i] name:@"file" fileName:stringFileName mimeType:@"text/plain"];
                       }

                   }

               }error:nil];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{
                                            @"Authorization": stringToken,
                                            };

    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

        NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
        uploadTask = [manager
                      uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request
                      progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

                      }
                      completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                          if (error) {

                              NSLog(@"ERROR ---%@",error);
                          }
                          else
                          {}];
```

Comment: The part of the code you’re showing doesn’t tell us anything about how you add the images to upload. Note that you are apparently getting the square of the number, so you probably have unnecessary nested loops somewhere.

Comment: I have added more codes. When I run my codes using breakpoint then its working fine, but when I just run completely the count differs